Transparent canvas with putImageData
I'm trying to render some flames however I cannot achieve a transparent canvas with putImageData(), resulting in a black canvas but well-drawn flames.
I tried "globalcompositeoperation" "source-over" and "globalAlpha" but to no avail.
The only issue is that the canvas draws a black background instead of rendering the flames with a transparent canvas background.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('fire');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
  var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
  var intensity = null;
  var fps = 30;
  var threshold = 0.5;
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  var data = imageData.data;
  var numPixels = data.length / 4;

  var colors = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    var color = [];
    color[0] = color[1] = color[2] = 0;
    colors[i] = color;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    colors[i][2] = i << 1;
    colors[i + 32][0] = i << 3;
    colors[i + 32][2] = 64 - (i << 1);
    colors[i + 64][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 64][1] = i << 3;
    colors[i + 96][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 96][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 96][2] = i << 2;
    colors[i + 128][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 128][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 128][2] = 64 + (i << 2);
    colors[i + 160][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 160][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 160][2] = 128 + (i << 2);
    colors[i + 192][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 192][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 192][2] = 192 + i;
    colors[i + 224][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 224][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 224][2] = 224 + i;
  }

  var fire = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < canvasWidth * canvasHeight; i++) {
    fire[i] = 0;
  }

  var time = new Date().getTime();

  function randomizeThreshold() {
    threshold += Math.random() * 0.2 - 0.1;
    threshold = Math.min(Math.max(threshold, 0.5), 0.8);
  }

  function burnBurnBurn() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(burnBurnBurn);
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    dt = now - time;

    if (dt < (1000 / fps))
      return;

    time = now;

    var bottomLine = canvasWidth * (canvasHeight - 1);

    for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x++) {
      var value = 0;

      if (Math.random() > threshold)
        value = 255;

      fire[bottomLine + x] = value;
    }

    var value = 0;

    for (var y = 0; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
      for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
        if (x == 0) {
          value = fire[bottomLine];
          value += fire[bottomLine];
          value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth];
          value /= 3;
        } else if (x == canvasWidth - 1) {
          value = fire[bottomLine + x];
          value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth + x];
          value += fire[bottomLine + x - 1];
          value /= 3;
        } else {
          value = fire[bottomLine + x];
          value += fire[bottomLine + x + 1];
          value += fire[bottomLine + x - 1];
          value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth + x];
          value /= 4;
        }

        if (value > 1)
          value -= 1;

        value = Math.floor(value);
        var index = bottomLine - canvasWidth + x;
        fire[index] = value;
      }

      bottomLine -= canvasWidth;
    }

    var skipRows = 2;

    for (var y = skipRows; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
      for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
        var index = y * canvasWidth * 4 + x * 4;
        var value = fire[(y - skipRows) * canvasWidth + x];

        data[index] = colors[value][0];
        data[++index] = colors[value][1];
        data[++index] = colors[value][2];
        data[++index] = 255;
      }
    }
    if (intensity == null) {
      if (Math.random() > 0.95) {
        randomizeThreshold();
      }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(burnBurnBurn);
});
<canvas id="fire"></canvas>




Create a second offscreen canvas the correct size to fit the flames. Put the flame imagedata on the second canvas and then draw the second (flames) canvas onto the main canvas  flamesCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0); ctx.drawImage(flamesCtx.canvas, 0, 0); You can then use composition and transform the flames to improve performance if flame FX is slow on some devices.

putImageData always replaces the destination pixel data without considering any composition options.
You need to set the alpha component on the ImageData itself:
   data[index] = colors[value][0];
   data[++index] = colors[value][1];
   data[++index] = colors[value][2];
/* data[++index] = 255; */
   data[++index] = value;



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('fire');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
  var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
  var intensity = null;
  var fps = 30;
  var threshold = 0.5;
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  var data = imageData.data;
  var numPixels = data.length / 4;

  var colors = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    var color = [];
    color[0] = color[1] = color[2] = 0;
    colors[i] = color;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    colors[i][2] = i << 1;
    colors[i + 32][0] = i << 3;
    colors[i + 32][2] = 64 - (i << 1);
    colors[i + 64][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 64][1] = i << 3;
    colors[i + 96][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 96][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 96][2] = i << 2;
    colors[i + 128][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 128][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 128][2] = 64 + (i << 2);
    colors[i + 160][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 160][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 160][2] = 128 + (i << 2);
    colors[i + 192][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 192][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 192][2] = 192 + i;
    colors[i + 224][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 224][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 224][2] = 224 + i;
  }

  var fire = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < canvasWidth * canvasHeight; i++) {
    fire[i] = 0;
  }

  var time = new Date().getTime();

  function randomizeThreshold() {
    threshold += Math.random() * 0.2 - 0.1;
    threshold = Math.min(Math.max(threshold, 0.5), 0.8);
  }

  function burnBurnBurn() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(burnBurnBurn);
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    dt = now - time;

    if (dt < (1000 / fps))
      return;

    time = now;

    var bottomLine = canvasWidth * (canvasHeight - 1);

    for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x++) {
      var value = 0;

      if (Math.random() > threshold)
        value = 255;

      fire[bottomLine + x] = value;
    }

    var value = 0;

    for (var y = 0; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
      for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
        if (x == 0) {
          value = fire[bottomLine];
          value += fire[bottomLine];
          value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth];
          value /= 3;
        } else if (x == canvasWidth - 1) {
          value = fire[bottomLine + x];
          value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth + x];
          value += fire[bottomLine + x - 1];
          value /= 3;
        } else {
          value = fire[bottomLine + x];
          value += fire[bottomLine + x + 1];
          value += fire[bottomLine + x - 1];
          value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth + x];
          value /= 4;
        }

        if (value > 1)
          value -= 1;

        value = Math.floor(value);
        var index = bottomLine - canvasWidth + x;
        fire[index] = value;
      }

      bottomLine -= canvasWidth;
    }

    var skipRows = 2;

    for (var y = skipRows; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
      for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
        var index = y * canvasWidth * 4 + x * 4;
        var value = fire[(y - skipRows) * canvasWidth + x];

        data[index] = colors[value][0];
        data[++index] = colors[value][1];
        data[++index] = colors[value][2];
        data[++index] = value;
      }
    }
    if (intensity == null) {
      if (Math.random() > 0.95) {
        randomizeThreshold();
      }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(burnBurnBurn);
});
<canvas id="fire"></canvas>




The most simple way to get rid of your black background is: don't draw it!
These following four lines of your code control the r, g, b and alpha values of a single pixel.
        data[index] = colors[value][0];
        data[++index] = colors[value][1];
        data[++index] = colors[value][2];
        data[++index] = 255;

As you can see we have a hard-coded alpha value of 255. Now if we know that the r, g and b values for black are three times 0 and we also know that we don't want to have any black, we can add a simple check if the pixel about to be drawn is black and in case it is, set it's alpha value to 0.
data[++index] = colors[value][0] == 0 && colors[value][1] == 0 && colors[value][2] == 0 ? 0 : 255;

The complete example:


var canvas = document.getElementById('fire');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
var intensity = null;
var fps = 30;
var threshold = 0.5;
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
var data = imageData.data;
var numPixels = data.length / 4;

var colors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  var color = [];
  color[0] = color[1] = color[2] = 0;
  colors[i] = color;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
  colors[i][2] = i << 1;
  colors[i + 32][0] = i << 3;
  colors[i + 32][2] = 64 - (i << 1);
  colors[i + 64][0] = 255;
  colors[i + 64][1] = i << 3;
  colors[i + 96][0] = 255;
  colors[i + 96][1] = 255;
  colors[i + 96][2] = i << 2;
  colors[i + 128][0] = 255;
  colors[i + 128][1] = 255;
  colors[i + 128][2] = 64 + (i << 2);
  colors[i + 160][0] = 255;
  colors[i + 160][1] = 255;
  colors[i + 160][2] = 128 + (i << 2);
  colors[i + 192][0] = 255;
  colors[i + 192][1] = 255;
  colors[i + 192][2] = 192 + i;
  colors[i + 224][0] = 255;
  colors[i + 224][1] = 255;
  colors[i + 224][2] = 224 + i;
}

var fire = [];

for (var i = 0; i < canvasWidth * canvasHeight; i++) {
  fire[i] = 0;
}

var time = new Date().getTime();

function randomizeThreshold() {
  threshold += Math.random() * 0.2 - 0.1;
  threshold = Math.min(Math.max(threshold, 0.5), 0.8);
}

function burnBurnBurn() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(burnBurnBurn);
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  dt = now - time;

  if (dt < (1000 / fps))
    return;

  time = now;

  var bottomLine = canvasWidth * (canvasHeight - 1);

  for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x++) {
    var value = 0;

    if (Math.random() > threshold)
      value = 255;

    fire[bottomLine + x] = value;
  }

  var value = 0;

  for (var y = 0; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
      if (x == 0) {
        value = fire[bottomLine];
        value += fire[bottomLine];
        value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth];
        value /= 3;
      } else if (x == canvasWidth - 1) {
        value = fire[bottomLine + x];
        value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth + x];
        value += fire[bottomLine + x - 1];
        value /= 3;
      } else {
        value = fire[bottomLine + x];
        value += fire[bottomLine + x + 1];
        value += fire[bottomLine + x - 1];
        value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth + x];
        value /= 4;
      }

      if (value > 1)
        value -= 1;

      value = Math.floor(value);
      var index = bottomLine - canvasWidth + x;
      fire[index] = value;
    }

    bottomLine -= canvasWidth;
  }

  var skipRows = 2;

  for (var y = skipRows; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
      var index = y * canvasWidth * 4 + x * 4;
      var value = fire[(y - skipRows) * canvasWidth + x];

      data[index] = colors[value][0];
      data[++index] = colors[value][1];
      data[++index] = colors[value][2];
      data[++index] = colors[value][0] == 0 && colors[value][1] == 0 && colors[value][2] == 0 ? 0 : 255;
    }
  }
  if (intensity == null) {
    if (Math.random() > 0.95) {
      randomizeThreshold();
    }
  }

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
};

window.requestAnimationFrame(burnBurnBurn);
<canvas id="fire"></canvas>




Because you are operating on the entire canvas setting their alpha values, when you should stick to the little area where the flames are rendered!
Therefore, these three changes were necessary...
var canvasHeight = canvas.height-430;

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 430, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 430);

The "430" is your "magic" number on a 500px high canvas... where your flames start, so stick to that area only!
Here’s the full program...


window.addEventListener('load', Init, false);

function Init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('fire');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
  var canvasHeight = canvas.height - 430;
  var intensity = null;
  var fps = 30;
  var threshold = 0.5;
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 430, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  var data = imageData.data;
  var numPixels = data.length / 4;

  var colors = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    var color = [];
    color[0] = color[1] = color[2] = 0;
    colors[i] = color;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    colors[i][2] = i << 1;
    colors[i + 32][0] = i << 3;
    colors[i + 32][2] = 64 - (i << 1);
    colors[i + 64][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 64][1] = i << 3;
    colors[i + 96][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 96][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 96][2] = i << 2;
    colors[i + 128][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 128][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 128][2] = 64 + (i << 2);
    colors[i + 160][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 160][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 160][2] = 128 + (i << 2);
    colors[i + 192][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 192][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 192][2] = 192 + i;
    colors[i + 224][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 224][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 224][2] = 224 + i;
  }

  var fire = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < canvasWidth * canvasHeight; i++) {
    fire[i] = 0;
  }

  var time = new Date().getTime();

  function randomizeThreshold() {
    threshold += Math.random() * 0.2 - 0.1;
    threshold = Math.min(Math.max(threshold, 0.5), 0.8);
  }

  function burnBurnBurn() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(burnBurnBurn);
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    dt = now - time;

    if (dt < (1000 / fps))
      return;

    time = now;

    var bottomLine = canvasWidth * (canvasHeight - 1);

    for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x++) {
      var value = 0;

      if (Math.random() > threshold) value = 255;

      fire[bottomLine + x] = value;
    }

    var value = 0;

    for (var y = 0; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
      for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
        if (x == 0) {
          value = fire[bottomLine];
          value += fire[bottomLine];
          value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth];
          value /= 3;

        } else if (x == canvasWidth - 1) {
          value = fire[bottomLine + x];
          value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth + x];
          value += fire[bottomLine + x - 1];
          value /= 3;
        } else {
          value = fire[bottomLine + x];
          value += fire[bottomLine + x + 1];
          value += fire[bottomLine + x - 1];
          value += fire[bottomLine - canvasWidth + x];
          value /= 4;
        }

        if (value > 1)
          value -= 1;

        value = Math.floor(value);
        var index = bottomLine - canvasWidth + x;
        fire[index] = value;
      }

      bottomLine -= canvasWidth;
    }

    var skipRows = 2;

    for (var y = skipRows; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
      for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
        var index = y * canvasWidth * 4 + x * 4;
        var value = fire[(y - skipRows) * canvasWidth + x];

        data[index] = colors[value][0];
        data[++index] = colors[value][1];
        data[++index] = colors[value][2];
        data[++index] = 255;
      }
    }

    if (intensity == null) {
      if (Math.random() > 0.95) {
        randomizeThreshold();
      }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 430);

  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(burnBurnBurn);
}
<canvas id="fire" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid silver;"></canvas>



Btw, you should never declare identifiers inside of loops or you'll run out of stack.
Go over each loop and move identifier declarations outside of the loops.

Thanks a lot for the valuable suggestions :) though the initial issue is that the flames still render with a black background instead of a fully transparent one, regardless of draw area.

@Leather - at a glance, I guess you need to use a distance function. This function tells you how far from [0,0,0] the colour of a pixel is. If this value is below a certain threshold (i.e close-enough to black) then set the pixel's opacity to 0.

Thanks for the answer and welcome to SO! "Btw, you should never declare identifiers inside of loops or you'll run out of stack. Go over each loop and move identifier declarations outside of the loops." is incorrect. Everything goes on the heap in JS, it's not C (and even if it was, there's plenty of stack unless you're allocating some huge array). Scope variables as tightly as possible. The answer also doesn't really solve OP's primary problem of making the entire background transparent.
